# Why is the interaction energy between two capacitor plates the energy of the electric field that exists between them?

Tags: electric-fields

My book says that the interaction energy between the two plates is actually the energy of the electric field that exists between the two plates. I would love to know if the experiment or the theory proves it. I would love to get an answer on this. Thank you!

Comment: What book and what author, this will help put context for those answering. I personally have not seen it stated that way but it would really depend on whose writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy stored in a capacitor is $\frac 12 QV = \frac 12 CV^2$ as $Q=CV$.
Foe a parallel plate capacitor with area of plates $A$ and separation of plates $d$ the capacitance $C$ is $\frac {\epsilon_0A}{d}$.
Thus the energy stored in a capacitor is $\dfrac {\epsilon_0AV^2}{2d}$.

The energy per unit volume stored in an electric field $E$ is $\frac 12 \epsilon_0 E^2$.
In a parallel plate capacitor $E=\frac Vd$, the potential gradient.

Thus the energy stored in a capacitor of volume $Vd$ is $\dfrac 12 \left( \dfrac Vd\right)^2\cdot Ad = \dfrac {\epsilon_0AV^2}{2d}$ as before.